# Java code keeps overriding old elements in list to the new element

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with my code here.

I have a list of recipe objects taken from a json file, but whenever I try to put in a new recipe object, it makes all the previous objects into this new object. This means I would have a list of 8 (or whatever) of the same recipe - i.e. the last object in the json file.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Hope I have provided enough material.

```
    private void fillItemsDB(String filename) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sContext.getAssets().open(filename)));
            String jsonString = reader.readLine();
            JSONArray recipeA = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i < recipeA.length(); i++) {
                RecipeItem ri = new RecipeItem();

                String rName = recipeA.getJSONObject(i).getString("gname");
                String rGuide = recipeA.getJSONObject(i).getString("gguide");

                ri.setRecipeName(rName);
                ri.setRecipeGuide(rGuide);

                list.add(ri); //arraylist

                addRecipe(ri);

            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON", je);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read file", e);
        }
        this.setChanged();
        notifyObservers();

    }

    public void addRecipe(RecipeItem recipeItem) {
        ContentValues values = getContentValues(recipeItem);
        mDatabase.insert(RecipeDbSchema.ItemTable.NAME, null, values);
        this.setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    private static ContentValues getContentValues(RecipeItem recipe) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(RecipeDbSchema.ItemTable.Cols.RecipeName, recipe.getRecipeName());
        values.put(RecipeDbSchema.ItemTable.Cols.RecipeGuide, recipe.getRecipeGuide());
        return values;
    }
```

Comment: with each loop you call `addRecipe(ri);` and by doing this also `this.setChanged();` and `notifyObservers();`. What happens in those methods? What do they trigger?

Comment: These are methods from the Observable class. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

Comment: I see, but what do they trigger? I could imagine that this is the flaw in your code. Because after the loop you call them again. Doesn't it suffice to call them only there?